# Suggestions on how to improve this logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, cs6, photoshop-effects, critique

So I'm trying  to make a logo that:

1. Represents two initials: L and R ;
2. The L is supposed to look somehow like a bird, you will see in the photo;
3. The letter R is going to be a lowercase "r" that's actually the L letter flipped on the floor, looking like an r but a shadow for the L letter(bird) at the same time.
4. The idea of the logo is "freedom" , hence the bird.
5. I'm trying to make it as simple as possible. Don't know if I should make it Black & White or add some color. I'm open to new ideas.

   The problem is, I truly don't know how to make this actually look good because i'm supposed to make the r as if it's a shadow, so I must make it look like a light is behind the L and that creates the shadow, making the photo look kind of 3D. If you could suggest me anything I could do to make it look good I would highly appreciate it! I am working in Photoshop CS6.
   (The logo is not necessarily supposed to be in a circle)
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Here's the bird concept stretched to another direction https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo76pljmo2nn30b/L_Bird.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I had no idea that was supposed to be a bird until I *read* that it was supposed to be a bird. I don't mean to imply that's a "bad" thing, but the bird concept is quite obscure.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of shadow you could play with reflection in water like this examples:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a really good suggestion, haven't thought about that :)

Comment: This answer is a nice tip, especially the second option, because a gradient or blur is not a good idea to be part of a logo.